# How can I decrypt my encrypted /home partition?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, password, home, ecryptfs

A year ago I installed Linux Mint 17 on my laptop. I partitioned the HDD and separated the system (`/` mount point) and the data (`/home` mount point). I chose to encrypt the whole `/home` using the basic mechanism provided by the Linux Mint installer (which is the same as in Ubuntu I think).

A year later (i.e. today) I want to replace Linux Mint by a plain old Debian (stable). I install it over the `/` mount point, keeping the `/home` one, hoping to retrieve my data later.

Installation succeed! But surprise: All my data are encrypted! :(

Is there any solution to retrieve the data?

Info :

- I remember the password I used to log in (which was, I suppose so, needed to decrypt the `/home`)
- I have access to the `/home/<oldlogin>/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase` file

Comment: Restore the / partition from your backup. Then login Mint 17 as usual using your password, copy the data from /home to a temporary device (reuse the backup device/medium if you are running short on storage). Install Debian once more and restore the /home.

Comment: @Anthon Thank you for your answer. But I don't have any backup of the / partition. :/

Answer (score 3):

Install the `ecryptfs` package.

Run the command [`ecryptfs-mount-private`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ecryptfs-mount-private&sektion=1). It will prompt you for a password, enter the password for your account on Mint.

Installing the package also adds [`pam_ecryptfs`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pam_ecryptfs&sektion=8) to the [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) configuration, so from now on, if you use the same password for your account and for your ecryptfs passphrase, your encrypted home directory will be automatically made accessible when you log in.

Comment: `ecryptfs-mount-private` returns `Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
ERROR: Your passphrase is incorrect` when I enter my old password. Anyway thank you.

Comment: @spfeiffer Hmmm. Are you sure you entered the correct password? I can't think of a reason why you'd get that last message otherwise (the first one could be harmless if you aren't running gnome-keyring). Do you get anything else in the system logs (whatever file gets modified in `/var/log`)? The maintainer of ecryptfs used to hang out on this site, hopefully he'll see your question, though I haven't seen him around much recently.

Comment: I tried several times. I installed Debian with the same user (i.e. login:password) as in Mint. Are you sure it has to be the password I was using to log in Mint? Syslog has this info: `ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring: Incorrect wrapping key for file [/home/login/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase]
ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring: Error attempting to unwrap passphrase from file [/home/login/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase]; rc = [-5]`